# webview android studio - input file not clickable

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'd like to open my website in a android app using webview.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");

    }
}
```

it is working fine. The problem is that I have a form in one PHP page that users can send images to my website. When user clicks in the button to pick pictures nothing happens. how can I solve this in an easy way?

I also added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Follow [this](https://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128) its helps.. but must use android 4.2 + Versions

Comment: @WhatsGoingOn thanks friend, I'll try!!

Answer (score 1):

set the webview

```
   webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webview.loadUrl(URL);
```

add the webchrome client for the file choosing image popup

```
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

            newWebView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
            newWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            newWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            newWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            view.addView(newWebView);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(newWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();
```

add the file chooser code

```
        // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
            if (uploadMessage != null) {
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
            uploadMessage = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
            try{
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                uploadMessage = null;
                Toast.makeText(act, "Cannot Open File Chooser", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

get the result chosen

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE){
            if (uploadMessage == null)
                return;
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
            uploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE){
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
        // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(act, "Failed to Upload Image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```